# Sending a Notification from a UIButton to a ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITableViewCell created in an external Nib from my storyboard. I have set up a segue from the UITableViewController to another ViewController which works nicely when tested.

I was wondering how would I get the UIButton in the Nib to call 
`[performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];` when it's pressed.

Any ideas? I'm still very amateurish so if you could explain quite clearly I'd really appreciate it.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also accomplish the same thing on the storyboard; right click the button and drag the arrow to the viewcontroller you want to navigate to, it will give the segue options (push, modal, custom) and just select one.

Comment: Is that possible when the button is in a different nib?

Comment: i dont believe so, which sdk do you use is it ios 5 because previous versions don't have storyboard

Comment: For most of the simple tasks storyboard should be sufficient, do you have specific reasons to use nib files (like reusability) otherwise I will suggest you to use storyboard instead of individual nib files

Comment: I decided to do this suggestion. I deleted the external nib and rebuilt the cell as a prototype cell. Much easier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController.h do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

In your .m file do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
}
```

Now go to your `.xib` File and connect the Buttons selector to your controller.

Comment: If the Button is in a separate nib, how can it call the IBAction in the ViewController?

Comment: You can connect to button action to the "File's Owner" which should be your ViewController.

Comment: I decided to remove the nib and create a prototype cell. Therefore I won't get to try this out. +1 for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

To handle it in your calling VC

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"identifier"]) {
        >yoursecondVC> *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondViewController.<param> = <param>;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've got the segue working fine, it's just calling it from a button in an external nib.